# Наибольшее количество последовательно идущих бит

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

*Даже удивлён тому, что подобная задача почти не светится в интернете... Задача близкая к разряду битовой магии*

Есть последовательность бит, кратная переменной 8-64 бит, к примеру: от 8 до 1024 бит.

**Задача:**
Нужно выдать наибольшее количество последовательно идущих нулевых бит.

**Или же другая постановка:**
Есть ли **N** последовательно идущих нулевых битов в исходной последовательности.

**Пример:** Приходит последовательность из 32 бит в соответствующей переменной:
(Десятичная) 1'426'241'534
(Двоичная) 0101 0101 0000 0010 1011 0111 1111 1110

Вывод для первого варианта задачи: 6 (нулей), 10 (в случае если считаем единицы)
Вывод для второго варианта задачи: ИСТИНА - Если мы ищем до 6 последовательных нулевых бит, или ЛОЖЬ если ищем больше, ибо такого количества уже нет.

Ищу способ более быстрый, чем нежели простой перебор циклом по одному биту с использованием аккумулятора.

Comment: В каком виде представлены входные данные? Если это _массив_ целых чисел (ноликов и единичек) или строка, то вполне возможно, что самый быстрый способ - "простой перебор циклом по одному биту[элементу массива/строки] с использованием аккумулятора". Если поток битов запакован в целые числа, например, в `uint64_t`, то тут возможно есть простор для оптимизации... (спец. инструкцией проверять кол-во единичных битов, например...)

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл
Да, второй вариант, сейчас также дополню вопрос

Comment: Похожая задача используется в паковщиках. Я думаю надо незабывать что 8 бит выровняных по границе 8 бит, либо же 15 последовательно идущих бит гарантировано дадут 255 0xFF. Анализ байт - будет всегда быстрее чем нанализ бит, поэтому хистрости с байтами-двойными словами - могут ускорить алгоритм, а могут не ускорить.

Comment: @nick_n_a
По байтам это тоже хорошо, благо кратно 8-64 байтам, как я выше уже уточнял.   
Могу обрисовать выше сказанное своей задачей:  
Есть битовая маска (занято/незанято) некого пространства, нужно найти то - поместится ли новый кусок данных и где, если согласно битовой маске новый кусок занимает к примеру 3 бита.

Comment: Не сказал бы, что всякая задача должна светится в интернете.  Такие типы задач относятся  не к разряду применимых, а относится к разряду "для любопытных"

Comment: @ARHovsepyan
Но всё же к разряду применимых. В моём же случае, такая функция будет одной из самых вызываемых по частоте. И работа с битовыми массивами, достаточно частое явление, когда важна скорость и экономность.

Comment: @NewTech,  Если вам нужно решать такую задачу, это не значит, что она нужна будет кому то еще, а тем более многим и часто. Это не хитрости с битовыми операциями, а  простая итерация по битам с применением  этих хитростей. И, честно говоря, я не понимаю почему в ответах  такие сложности, когда все очень просто.

Comment: Хорошо бы наверно дополнительно перечислить процессы где такое используется. Потому что обычно никто не знает зачем это нужно, в исходном виде - задача весьма абстрактная. Обычно и правда всё находится "под капотом" и мало кто знает где такое используется. Обычно такая операция используется: паковщики-компрессоры, некоторые менеджеры памяти. А такое обычно никто не пишет с нуля, а если кто-то такое пишет - то такой программист имеет достаточно знаний в данной области.

Comment: @nick_n_a Хм... может я какой то неправильный, ибо с подобными вещами сталкиваюсь достаточно часто, а вот сейчас так совсем припёрло к стенке. Кстати мне к сожалению приходится писать некоторые вещи ну прям совсем с нуля. А еще кстати люди потом 
 удивляются, как это у тебя 2 миллиона транзакций в сек, а еще на одном ядре.

Не стоит судить раньше времени.

Comment: @nick_n_a Как и хорошо когда задачи достаточно абстрактные, так как зачастую важна именно идея, как это сделать, или же сделать лучше, чем наивным образом. Решение под свою специфичную задачу проще сделать из абстрактного (общего), чем нежели разбирать чьё то решение.
Повторюсь, я часто вижу нужду в применения подобной штуки, когда речь доходит до битовых маск. Не помню чьи слова...: Быстродействие, это история о кэшировании кэшей...

Answer (score 3):

Разобьём входной поток битов на блоки фиксированного размера (например, по восемь бит). Подсчитать наибольшее количество подряд идущих нулевых битов можно анализируя такие блоки.

```
00010000 | 00010010 | 00101000
   i-1        i          i+1
```

Упрощённое описание алгоритма. Пусть сейчас мы анализируем `i`-тый блок. С предыдущего `i-1`-ого шага мы получим две величины:

- `zeros_max` — текущей максимум подряд идущих нулей,
- `zeros_old` — длина хвоста из нулей, которым заканчиваются предыдущие блоки.

Если `i`-тый блок не содержит ни одного единичного бита, то мы просто нарастим хвост из нулей на длину блока и перейдём к следующему `i+1`-ому блоку.
Если `i`-тый блок содержит хотябы один единичный бит, то необходим дополнительный анализ текущего блока.

Биты ненулевого блока (содержащего хотя бы один единичный бит) можно разделить на три группы:

- Ведущие нули — все нулевые биты в начале блока (слева). Данное множество может быть пусто.
- Оконечные нули — все нулевые биты в конце блока (справа). Данное множество также может быть пусто.
- Центральные биты — все биты начиная с самой первой единицы (самой левой) и заканчивая последней единицей (самой правой). Данное множество может не содержать ни одного нулевого бита.

В ненулевом блоке прерывается последовательность из нулей, поэтому необходимо пересчитать текущий максимум подряд идущих нулей.

1. Если длина хвоста из нулей `zeros_old`, полученная с предыдущего шага, в сумме с ведущими нулями текущего блока больше текущего максимума, то обновляем максимум.
2. Если максимальная нулевая последовательность внутри "центральных битов" длиннее, чем текущий максимум, то обновляем максимум.

На следующий шаг передаём обновлённый максимум и в качестве "хвоста" — длину оконечных нулей текущего блока.

Более детальный алгоритм в псевдокоде:

```
//Предварительный шаг.
zeros_old = 0;
zeros_max = 0;

//Перебираем блоки
for (auto block: data)
{
    if (block == 0)
        zeros_old += bits_in_block;
    else
    {
        zeros_old += block_left;
        zeros_max = max(zeros_max, block_center, zeros_old);
        zeros_old = block_right;
    }
}

//Заключительный шаг
zeros_max = max(zeros_max, zeros_old);
```

Приведённый алгоритм для каждого блока требует расчёта количества ведущих/оконечных нулей и длину максимальной нулевой подпоследовательности среди центральных битов. Однако, количество возможных попарно различных блоков не очень велико. Для 8-битного блока — 256 вариантов, для 16-битного блока — 65536 вариантов. Можно предварительно рассчитать все необходимые данные для каждого возможного блока, занести в массив и вместо непосредственного подсчёта битов извлекать необходимые данные из массива.

---

Вот набросок кода.

Вспомогательная структура для хранения характеристик блоков:

```
struct block_stat
{
    std::uint_least8_t left;
    std::uint_least8_t center;
    std::uint_least8_t right;
};
```

Функция расчёта характеристик блока (`block_type` — беззнаковый целочисленный тип для хранения битов блока, `bits_in_block` — количество битов в блоке, `block` — биты блока, упакованные в целочисленную переменную (более левый бит соответствует более младшему в целочисленной переменной)):

```
template <typename block_type, int bits_in_block>
block_stat get_block_stat(block_type block)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<block_type>::digits >= bits_in_block);
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<std::uint_least8_t>::max() >= bits_in_block);
    
    std::uint_least8_t left = 0, center = 0, right = 0;
    bool flag_first = true;

    for (int shift = 0; shift < bits_in_block; ++shift)
    {
        int bit = (block >> shift) & 1;
        if (bit == 0)
            ++right;
        else
        {
            if (flag_first)
            {
                flag_first = false;
                left = right;
            }
            else if (right > center)
                center = right;
            right = 0;
        }
    }

    block_stat result = {left, center, right};
    return result;
}
```

Следующая функция, возвращающает вектор характеристик всевозможных блоков (функция перебирает все блоки длины `bits_in_block` начиная с полностью нулевого и заканчивая полностью единичным. Для полностью нулевого блока полагается по-определению: `left = center = 0; right = bits_in_block`):

```
template <typename block_type, int bits_in_block>
std::vector<block_stat> get_stat_arr()
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<block_type>::digits >= bits_in_block);

    block_type max_block_value = 0;
    for (int bit = 0; bit < bits_in_block; ++bit)
        max_block_value = max_block_value * 2 + 1;
    
    typedef std::vector<block_stat>::size_type size_type;
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() > max_block_value, "!!!");
    const size_type stat_arr_size = size_type(1) + max_block_value;

    std::vector<block_stat> stat_arr;
    stat_arr.reserve(stat_arr_size);

    for (size_type i = 0; i < stat_arr_size; ++i)
        stat_arr.push_back(get_block_stat<block_type, bits_in_block>(i));
    return stat_arr;
}
```

Наконец, функция, реализующая описанный алгоритм (принимает на вход последовательность битов, запакованную в вектор октетов и вектор характеристик блоков. `octets_in_block` — количество октетов отображаемых в один блок. Если длина блока `8` бит, то равно `1`, если длина блока `16` бит, то равно `2`):

```
template <typename block_type, int octets_in_block>
std::size_t search_longest_seq(const std::vector<std::uint_least8_t>& data, const std::vector<block_stat>& stat_arr)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<block_type>::digits / 8 >= octets_in_block);
    
    std::size_t zeros_old = 0;
    std::size_t zeros_max = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i += octets_in_block)
    {
        block_type block = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < octets_in_block; ++j)
            block |= (data[i + j] & 255) << j * 8;

        if (block == 0)
            zeros_old += stat_arr[block].right;
        else
        {
            zeros_old += stat_arr[block].left;
            if (zeros_old > zeros_max)
                zeros_max = zeros_old;
            if (stat_arr[block].center > zeros_max)
                zeros_max = stat_arr[block].center;
            zeros_old = stat_arr[block].right;
        }
    }
    if (zeros_old > zeros_max)
        zeros_max = zeros_old;
    return zeros_max;
}
```

Использовать можно так:

```
const std::size_t data_size = 200`000`000;
std::vector<std::uint_least8_t> data;
data.reserve(data_size);

std::mt19937 mt;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data_size; ++i)
    data.push_back(mt() % 256);

std::vector<block_stat> stat_arr = get_stat_arr<std::uint_least8_t, 8>();
//std::vector<block_stat> stat_arr = get_stat_arr<std::uint_least16_t, 16>();

std::size_t data_local_size = 1; //2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 128, data.size();
std::vector<std::uint_least8_t> data_local(data_local_size, 0);

std::size_t longest_seq = 0;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i+=data_local_size)
{
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < data_local_size; ++j)
        data_local[j] = data[i + j];
    longest_seq += search_longest_seq<std::uint_least8_t, 1>(data_local, stat_arr);
    //longest_seq += search_longest_seq<std::uint_least16_t, 2>(data_local, stat_arr);
    //longest_seq += search_longest_seq_simple(data_local);
}
```

Суть приведённого кода в следующем. Генерируется вектор из `200'000'000` октетов (который можно интерпретировать как длинную битовую последовательность). Разбивается на подвектора из 1, или 2, или 4, или 8, и т.д. элементов. У данных подвекторов ищется нулевая подпоследовательность максимальной длины тремя разными способами: с помощью разбиения на 8-битные блоки, с помощью разбиения на 16-битные блоки и "в лоб" с помощью функции `search_longest_seq_simple`:

```
std::size_t search_longest_seq_simple(const std::vector<std::uint_least8_t>& data)
{
    std::size_t zeros_bits = 0;
    std::size_t zeros_max = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::uint_least8_t octet = data[i];
        for (int shift = 0; shift < 8; ++shift)
        {
            int bit = (octet >> shift) & 1;
            if (bit == 0)
                ++zeros_bits;
            else
            {
                if (zeros_bits > zeros_max)
                    zeros_max = zeros_bits;
                zeros_bits = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (zeros_bits > zeros_max)
        zeros_max = zeros_bits;
    return zeros_max;
}
```

Время работы на моей системе такое (в секундах, без учёта времени генерации вспомогательного массива.):

```
Эл-ов      | Время, сек
           | simple |  8bit | 16bit
1            12.297   3.906   
2            11.797   2.891   2.078   
4            11.063   2.234   1.562   
8            10.578   1.766   1.25   
16           10.313   1.328   1.078   
32           10.141   1.062   0.844   
64           10.046   0.86    0.719   
128          10.063   0.812   0.703   
200000000    9.969    0.703   0.609
```

Если в алгоритме генерации заменить строку `data.push_back(mt() % 256);` на `data.push_back(mt() % 2);`, то время станет таким:

```
Эл-ов      | Время, сек
           | simple |  8bit | 16bit
1            4.453    2.485   
2            4.765    1.953   1.907   
4            4.359    1.656   1.421   
8            4.25     1.719   1.125   
16           4.063    1.625   1.047   
32           3.906    1.562   0.938   
64           3.844    1.5     0.844   
128          3.906    1.532   0.844   
200000000    3.844    1.469   0.782
```

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю надо незабывать что 8 бит выровняных по границе 8 бит, либо же 15 последовательно идущих бит гарантировано дадут 255 0xFF. Анализ байт - будет всегда быстрее чем анализ бит, поэтому хистрости с байтами-двойными словами - могут ускорить алгоритм.

Я за рациональное использовние массива. Тут он поможет.
Я предлагаю построить две или три таблицы. Таблица на 256 числел. Одна таблица - макс колличество бит в байте. Вторая - макс к-во бит слева (если таких нет - ноль). Третья таблица - максимальное к-во бит справа. Эти таблицы упростят анализ данных. Можно будет собрать максимумы значений по этим таблицам, а за тем уже детально анализировать сами биты в районе найденых максимумов.

```
      //                0  1 10 11,100,101,110,111, 
 unsigned char[] Мt = { 0 ,0,1 ,0, 1,0,2,0,    }; // Составите самостоятельно
 unsigned char[] Lt = { 0 ,0,0 ,0, 0,0,0,0,      }; // Составите самостоятельно
 unsigned char[] Rt = { 0, 1,0 ,2,0,1,0,3 }; // Составите самостоятельно
 
unsigned char maxM = 0, maxL = 0, maxR = 0;
int iM = 0,  iL = 0, iR = 0;

 
 for (int i=0;i<datasize;i++) {
    if (Мt[data[i]] > maxM) { maxM = Mt[data[i]]; iM = i; };
    if (Lt[data[i]] > maxL) { maxL = Lt[data[i]]; iL = i; };
    if (Rt[data[i]] > maxR) { maxR = Rt[data[i]]; iR = i; };
    }
```

Из Mt можно выкинуть случаи которые включают Lt и Rt - от этого результат получения ответа только ускорится. Если этого не сделать - на ответ не повлияет.

А дальше... Самый плохой случай когда maxL = maxR = maxM - тогда прийдётся анализировать все случаи.

На счёт найденого максимума - надо найти все такие максимумы - и все проанализировать (если массив на 10, iL = 3, maxL=6 это означает что Lt[data[7]] может тоже равняться 6 и его нужно тоже проверить). Если нашли L, то к-во бит будет Lt(i) + Rt(i-1) что через таблицы выяснится быстро. Но для 8 прийдётся делать исключение. Главное - данная идея позволяет полностью отказаться от анализа бит битовыми операциями в даной задаче.

Современные мощности позволяют сделать массив не на 8, а на 16 бит (65к массив), что ускорит анализ (я так думаю). 24-тоже думаю можно (16 мегабайт массив, 48 мегабайт можно организовать, но будет слегка запутано, и будут потери на отсекание 4-того байта, плюс наполнение массива может по времени превысить время расчётов). 32-бита уже будет точно нерационально. Что выиграет по времени 8 бит или 16 сказать сложно.

Для вашего случая

```
 i         0         1         2         3
 data      0101 0101 0000 0010 1011 0111 1111 1110
 M          1        1          2        0
 L          0        0          1        7
 R          1        0          3        0
 Тут мы получим          
  maxM = 2         iM = 2.
  maxL = 7         iL = 3
  maxR = 3         iR = 2
```

Тут случай когда из трех вариантов максимум один. Это `maxL = 7, iL = 3`.
Нужно по L проверить все максимумы,  - тут таких нету. `maxM` - нужен что бы выявить случай, когда средних бит будет больше чем сумма крайних - если подкинут допустим 6 бит в середине байта.

К-во бит будет `R[iL-1] + maxL`. Так как `R[iL-1]` не равно 8, то никаких доп-операций делать не нужно. `R[iL-1] + maxL` = 3 + 7 = 10.
Тут ответ 10.
Для к-во бит свыше 15 алгоритм усложнится.

UDP. Можно также, допустим анализировать не maxL maxR, а анализировать L+R вместе, тогда будет maxLR плюс maxM, и алгоритм будет проще но чуть запутаннее, т.к. переход через 8 бит будет реализован немного сложнее, но кажется данный алгоритм в итоге получается проще предыдущего. Но принцип тот же.

```
 unsigned char maxM = 0, maxRL = 0;
 int iM = 0,  iRL = 0;
 for (int i=0;i<(datasize-1);i++) {
     t = Rt[data[i]] + Lt[data[i+1]];
     // Переход через 8 бит - добавить
     if (t > maxRL ) { maxRL = t; iRL = i; };
     if (Mt[data[i]]>maxM) { maxM = Mt[data[i]]; iM = i; };
     }
  // последнее среднее выпало
  if (Mt[data[datasize-1]]>maxM) { maxM=Mt[data[datasize-1]]; iM = datasize-1; };
  if ( Rt[data[datasize-1]] > max) {...}; // крайний справа выпал, надо проверить
  if ( Lt[data[0]] > max) {...}; //крайний слева выпал, надо проверить
```

тогда (звездочка - это те значения которые выпали из цикла)

```
 i         0         1         2         3
 data      0101 0101 0000 0010 1011 0111 1111 1110
 M          1        1          2        0*
 L+R        1        0          10       -
 L          0*        0          1        7
 R          1        0          3        0*
```

Результат получается даже быстрее.

Так же можно сжать таблицы L R тернарными выражениями в 2 раза (там например если все чётные - нули, или если меньше 128 - то все левые нули), если есть ограничения по сегменту данных - то можно сжать в 4 раза задействовав старшие младшие биты например. Можно пропускать мелкие проверки, если найден максимум свыше определенного колличества бит. Например проверку средних tM Или некоторые финальные проверки.

P.S. Не забываем про [rtlfindsetbits](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlfindsetbits), думаю с ней можно сверяться. На счёт того оптимизирована она или неочень - не знаю. Функция "спрятана" в ntdll.dll, подключать прийдётся "вручную". Так же есть библиотеки... но я так понял интерисует больше реализация.

Ради интереса, попробую построить таблицу на 4 бита, что бы увидеть что математических аналогов этому нет. На 4 бита... ну я не думаю что хорошее решение реализовать такую задачу, но при желании можно.

```
D 0 1 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
R 0 1 0    2    0    1    0    3    0    1    0    2    0    1    0    4
M 0 0 1    0    1    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
L 0 0 0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    2    2    3    4
```

Comment: Не забыли, что в вопросе **до 1024 бит** (т.е. 128 байт)? А вы предлагаете массивы какого размера использовать для поиска?

Comment: В большинстве случаев при работе с битами поступают двумя способами - или массив, или сдвиг. Возможно используя какие-то команды ассемблера, допустим с набора mmx можно решить эту задачу, для 128 байт боюсь что через статические два/три массива эта задача будет решаться быстрее, чем через сдвиги and or или другие операции. Разве что.. 16 бит врядли нужно использовать.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что даже тупое побитовое сканирование 128 байт (особенно, если выбирать по 8 (т.е. 64 бита)) будет быстрее, чем построение хитрой 65Кбайтной таблицы

Comment: Три статические таблицы на 256 элементов - это меньше килобайта. 8битная таблица хорошо сработает. Таблицы видя пример - можно даже в 2 раза ужать тернарным выражением - тогда будет не 768 байт, а 384байта. При желании можно даже в 4 раза сжать используя старшие младшие биты или чётные нечетные биты байта. Понятно что для экономии времени таблицу лучше сгенерировать отдельно, и добавить в сегмент данных в виде голых чисел.

Comment: 16-битная таблица - допустим с 2-кратным сжатием можно построить таблицы в дата-сегменте, и применить в своём кодеке/компрессоре или там где большие потоки данных. Учитывая что страницы памяти в современных процессорах уже часто бывают 64к (т.е. у многих современные компы), то я вполне допускаю что правильно построенная программа на 16бит может в отдельных тестах потягаться с 8-битной и даже уложить её (т.к циклы в 2 раза короче). В соревнованиях требования жёще, и там прийдётся вкладываться в рамки задания, и думаю лучше отказаться от такого эксперимента, но тут об этом кажется не идет речь.

Answer (score -1):

Нашлось достаточно элегантное решение: https://gist.github.com/pushoo-sharma/d27a1d8cda4e3d348edfec82e94c816d

Суть заключается в том, что мы можем битовой операцией (x & (x << 1)) удалять последнюю единицу в каждой суб-последовательности единиц в исходной последовательности, тем самым сложность выполнения задачи у нас равняется О(E) - где E - наидлиннейшая суб-последовательность единиц в исходной последовательности.
А искать нули или единицы - это не важно, благодаря операции инвертирования ~ .

Пример из источника:

```
  11101111  (x)  
& 11011110  (x << 1)
--------------------------------  
  11001110  (x & (x << 1))
```

Соответственно проводя итерации дальше получим:

```
№0 - 11101111  
№1 - 11001110  
№2 - 10001100  
№3 - 00001000  
№4 - 00000000
```

Для данного примера нам понадобилось провести 4 итерации циклом:

```
FUNCTION(unsigned x) {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (x!=0)
    {
        x = (x & (x << 1));
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Просто, красиво и для размера типа переменных.
Для второго варианта задачи нужно лишь немного изменить подход, ограничив количество итераций цикла лимитом переданного параметра.

Соответственно решая задачу по расширению обработки последовательности бит больше чем 64 бита, необходимо запомнить начальные и конечные последовательности. Для этого мы в тело цикла можем добавить дополнительную операцию, по подсчёту битов с начала и конца с использованием дополнительного аккумулятора, и это почти не будет занимать такты, так как будет исполняться параллельно в теле цикла в месте с "(x & (x << 1))".

Нечто этакое (кусочек только для подсчёта битов в конце):

```
unsigned y = x;
unsigned int count2 = Z; // Где Z - это count3 из прошлой последовательности
unsigned int count3 = 0;
while {  
...
count3 += y & 1; 
y >>= y & 1;
}
// return max( count1, count2 );
```

Возвращая count2 для работы со следующим числом.

Из ярких плюсов:

- Это просто.
- Нет занимает память в L1 кэше
- Нет непредсказуемых ветвлений, и соответствующих вытекающих.

И суммарно значит, что это явно быстро

Также данную процедуру еще легко улучшить через SSE и AVX инструкции.

Вот один из примеров реализации:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long u8; // __int64

int main()
{
    const u8 FIRST_BIT = ~(((u8)-1)>>1);
    
    u8 arr[4]={ ~988555856555856699 , ~988555888855556699 , ~128555856555856600, ~123456789123456789 };
    cout<<std::bitset<64>(arr[0])<<" ";
    cout<<std::bitset<64>(arr[1])<<" ";
    cout<<std::bitset<64>(arr[2])<<" ";
    cout<<std::bitset<64>(arr[3])<<endl;
    
    u8 count1 = 0;
    u8 count2 = 0;
    u8 count3 = 0;
    u8 ret_max=0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        u8 x = arr[i];
        u8 y = arr[i];
        u8 z = arr[i];
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = count3;
        count3 = 0;
        
        while (x!=0)
        {
            count1++;
            x = (x & (x << 1));
            
            count2 += (y & FIRST_BIT) >> (sizeof(y)*8 - 1); 
            y <<= y & FIRST_BIT;
            
            count3 += z & 1; 
            z >>= z & 1;
            
        }
        
        ret_max = max(count1, ret_max);
        ret_max = max(count2, ret_max);
    }
    cout<<endl<<"MAX: "<<ret_max;
}
```

Вывод:

```
1111001001000111111100011010111110100001010110110010110011000100   
1111001001000111111100011010100000011100001001001101110110100100   
1111111000110111010001110010000100101100001100010010110100100111   
1111111001001001011001001011010001010011001011111010000011101010

MAX: 10
```

Примерно в таком духе

Comment: А вы проверяли работу представленной функции?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 
Да, прикрепил реализацию... как то поспешно уже минусуют ответ...

Comment: Теперь вы сами судите, должно быть хотя бы одно из этих всех решений в интернете  в качестве хитрости с битовыми операциями?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду...

Comment: Имею ввиду, что тут нет никакой "магии" а есть обыкновенная функция

Comment: @ARHovsepyan
Мне также кажется, что вы несколько зациклились не на том.